# Why get TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable?

Tags: python, html, flask

I don't know whats wrong with this code, but get "**TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable**"
It's properly works for '/filestream' but not for '/allfile'

python code

```
@app.route('/allfile')
@login_required
def allfile():
    fileStream = models.File.select().limit(100)
    return render_template('filestream.html', filestream=filestream)

@app.route('/filestream')
#@app.route('/filestream/<username>')
def filestream(username=None):
    template = 'fileStream.html'
    if username and username != current_user.username:
        user =     models.User.select().where(models.User.username**username).get() # the ** is     the "like" operator (non-case sensitive comparison)
        filestream = user.files.limit(100)
    else:
        filestream = current_user.get_filestream().limit(100)
        user = current_user
    #if username:
        #template = 'user_stream.html'
    return render_template(template, filestream=filestream, user=user)
```

HTML code

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% for file in filestream %}
  <article>
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ url_for('filestream', username=file.user.username) }}">
        {{ file.user.username }}
      </a>
    </h2>
    <i class="clock"></i>
    <time data-time="{{ file.timestamp }}" }}">
      {{ file.timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}
    </time>
   <!-- <a href="{{ url_for('view_file', file_id=file.id) }}"     class="view">View</a>-->
    <div class="file">
        <a href="{{ file.path}}"</a>
       <img src="{{ file.path }}" alt=""     style="width:521px;height:512px;"> 
    </div>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: provide full Traceback please

Comment: Also the rest of your python code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `allfile()` you define a local variable called `fileStream`, with a capital S. But what you pass to the template is `filestream`, with lower-case S; this isn't defined locally, so Python uses the module-level name which refers to the `filestream()` handler.

Make sure you're using consistent capitalization in your functions.